# what is the use of libGLES_CM.so?

Tags: linux, embedded, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on embedded device and trying to figure-out basics of opengl-es-2.0, I am not able to understand what is the usage of libGLES_CM.so? what functionality does it provides? why there are two opengl-es related libraries 1). libGLESv2.so and 2). libGLES_CM.so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is there for OpenGL-ES 1.0, If there are two libraries 1). libGLESv2.so and 2). libGLES_CM.so available on Embedded Device, this means that board supports both opengl ES 1.0 and opengl ES 2.0.